# How to pass specific ListTile variables to new page route onTap?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My code builds a ListView of ListTiles, with each ListTile getting data from a cloud firestore database.

When I activate the onTap of a ListTile I would like to route to a new page and pass the specific data for that tile to the new page.

The page which I am building the list view on I have passed variables to without problems, however I cannot get the same method to work on this page.

I am fairly new to flutter and dart. My first assumption is that maybe it requires a stateful widget in order to accomplish this? However I am not exactly sure how to implement this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:menu/screens/menu/detail.dart';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

class Menu extends StatelessWidget {
    final String barcode;

  // receive data from the FirstScreen as a parameter
  Menu({Key key, @required this.barcode}) : super(key: key);

  Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.fastfood),
      title: Text(document['item'] ?? '*name*'),
      subtitle: Text( document['description'] ?? '*description*'),
      isThreeLine: true,
      onTap: (){
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Detail(),
        ),);
        },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Menu'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection(barcode).snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('loading...');
            return ListView.builder(
              itemExtent: 80.0,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                  _buildListItem(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `document` as parameter to `Detail`

```
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Detail(document), // <-- document instance
    ),);
```

`Detail` widget of course need to take `document` as parameter:

```
class Detail extends ... {
  Detail(this.document);
  final DocumentSnapshot document;
}
```

as described in https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Comment: I had tried this previously but it throws the error: 'too many positional arguments: 0 expected but one found'

Comment: You need to add `document` as parameter in `Detail` widget, or if using named parameters, then `Detail(document: document)`